# Cucumber scenarios don't run when is task invoked in a lib/tasks task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake

I have the following task in lib/tasks:

```
    task :cuke_test_db_constraints do
      puts 'cuke_test_db_constraints'
      ENV['TEST_DB_CONSTRAINTS'] = '1'
      Rake::Task['cucumber'].reenable
      Rake::Task['cucumber'].invoke
    end

    task :default => :cuke_test_db_constraints
```

As you see, I want to run cucumber again after setting an env variable. However, while cuke_test_db_constraints task runs, cucumber doesn't run scenarios. The cucumber task itself runs, I checked it with adding debug output under :cucumber task in lib/tasks/cucumber.rake.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that if I run `rake cuke_test_db_constraints`, then it works, but if I just use `rake`, it doesn't.

Comment: I've found a workaround: user cucumber:ok task name, then it works.

Comment: You should write that below if you've answered yourself.

Comment: I think you could also add `=> :environment` after the task name. Might not be picking up everything correctly without that guy.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare that the `cucumber` task depends on `cuke_test_db_constraints` instead of imperatively invoking the task.

```
task :cuke_test_db_constraints do
  puts 'cuke_test_db_constraints'
  ENV['TEST_DB_CONSTRAINTS'] = '1'
end

task :default => :cucumber
task :cucumber => :cuke_test_db_constraints
```